# ShareStatusTask and ShareLinkTask in WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I'm developing a WP8.1 App in which I need to share a status and links from my app. ShareStatusTask and ShareLinkTask are not working. Can someone please tell how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google might help you. In windows phone 8.1 sharing changed like as Windows Store app. You have to use `DataTransferManager` for this

Add an event in OnNavigatedTo function :

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Register the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager = DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView();
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested += OnDataRequested;
}
```

Method to share :

```cs
protected void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "Some title";
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "Some description"; // Optional
    e.Request.Data.SetUri(new Uri("http://www.some_uri.com"));
}
```

Detach Event on OnNavigatedFrom :

```cs
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // Unregister the current page as a share source.
    _dataTransferManager.DataRequested -= OnDataRequested;
}
```

Look at this Blog for Source : [Link](http://www.jayway.com/2014/04/16/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-contracts/#scid:887EC618-8FBE-49a5-A908-2339AF2EC720:6f9bdaa7-a55f-450f-9974-2418aa258603)

Comment: Ok just tried this and it does absolutely nothing. Why do Microsoft take something simple like the sharetasklink and turn it into something painful